# Are there tools to auto-format Tcl source code?

Tags: formatting, tcl

I am using a vanilla vim editor to write [Tcl](https://www.tcl-lang.org) source code. Are there any UNIX programs to aid in auto-formatting of Tcl source code, similar to [rustfmt](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustfmt) for Rust or [gofmt](https://golang.org/cmd/gofmt/) for Go?

Answer (score 2):

It's not normally done as it is in general very hard to figure out what is code and what isn't (for formal reasons; the code/data duality is a bit closer to the surface in Tcl than many other languages). But most code can be handled [fairly easily](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Reformatting+Tcl+code+indentation) as long as you're aware that there are cases it will get wrong. Those cases are probably rare in your code.